# Migrate Fox Pro DBF files to SQL Server 2012 x64

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, dbf

I have among 80 and 100 Fox Pro DBF database files that I want to migrate to MSSQL Server 2012 x64.

Because are too much DBF data bases I'm looking for an automatic/non Manual way of move all data contained in these DBF files to MSSQL Server Data base Tables. One separate table for each DBF File.

I have tried the following code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL', 'Driver=Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver;
SourceDB=F:\SomeDBFPath;
SourceType=DBF',
'SELECT  * FROM someDBFFile')
```

in order to see/explore the data of one DBF, but the following error messages appears:

OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" returns an error.
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)"

I'm not interesed in use external software like a DBF converter or similar tools.

At this time I have installed the AccessDatabaseEngine_X64 file located at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 due to previous recommedations with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to Visual FoxPro?   If so, you can via the default menu of Tools -> Wizards -> Upsizing.

First, go into Control Panel, Administrative Tools.  Under that is ODBC Data Sources (should be a 32-bit version).  Go into that and then go to the tab for "System DSN" and click Add button to the right.  You will then be prompted to "name" the connection.  For grins, something like "UpsizeMyData".  It will then prompt you through the connection information to the database you are trying to connect to, user / password for connection, etc.  Go through and create the ODBC connection info and make sure the "Test Connection" at the end is successful.

Once this is done, get into VFP.  From the menu steps above, it will bring up a dialog window for transferring a database.  It will prompt you for the database you want to upsize... pick via a "Get File" dialog.  After that, it will prompt you with connection information, the ODBC connection you just created above should be listed.  Select that, then "Next".  It will then prompt you for the SQL password to start the connection.

Once connected, it will look though your database and look at the tables.  You will have a side-by-side picker dialog of all available tables and you can pick those you want to upsize... you can do one, many or all, then click "Next".

The next dialog will show you each of the tables you've chosen and allow you to confirm the data type from the VFP table to the corresponding column data type when pushed up to SQL.  You can try by letting the defaults go and try.  Click "Next".

Finally it will ask you which database you want to upsize to.  You can pick an existing database, OR Add a new (may be your choice for first time to see how things go).

Comment: Is there a Visual FoxPro for Windows x64?

Comment: @user80024, no, only 32-bit, but you should still be able to run it to upsize to sql database, even if the sql database is 64-bit.

Comment: Can you giveme more details in relation with your suggetion?

Comment: @user80024, revised answer to show steps as best as possible.